# Placing beam between staves with autochanging voice in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, beaming

I have a `PianoStaff` with two voices on the right hand. The lower voice with eighths is spread across the staves with `\autochange` and the additional pitch parameter nicely controls the turning point.

However, the beam of the eighth notes is placed below the left hand staff which doesn't look very nicely.

[image: 1]]

There are similar questions about this topic here but they didn't help me with the issue. I strongly prefer `\autochange` as manual changes can become somewhat tedious. How can I put the beam between the staves as indicated in blue?

Here's the code:

```
\version "2.19.83"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff
  <<
    \new Staff = "up" {
      << 
        {
          \relative c' { \clef bass <g b d>2 <g b> }
        }
        \\
        {
          \autochange b, { d8 g, d g, d g, d g, }
        }
      >>
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
      \clef bass
      \new Voice {
        \relative c, { g1 }
      }
    }
  >>
}
```

Comment: Is this what you need? http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-keyboards#cross_002dstaff-stems

Comment: @Vitulus I'm afraid not. This is about cross-staff stems, not beams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to restore the default stem direction with `\revert Stem.direction` because the notes are in a voice that has set the stem direction to `DOWN`. Use this:

```
\version "2.19.83"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff
  <<
    \new Staff = "up" {
      << 
        {
          \relative c' { \clef bass <g b d>2 <g b> }
        }
        \\
        {
          \revert Stem.direction                      % <--- added
          \autochange b, { d8 g, d g, d g, d g, }
        }
      >>
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
      \clef bass
      \new Voice {
        \relative c, { g1 }
      }
    }
  >>
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Can this be done with version 2.18.2? Your code doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos The command I added should also work in version 2.18.2. The above example does not work because of the `\autochange` command, which only accepts an additional argument to define the turning point in older versions of LilyPond. So, I think, you should ask a new question with your example.